# ffmpeg concat with filter eats up all memory

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-encoding, concatenation

I have been trying to produce a indefinite loop of a list of videos in a folder. For testing purpose, I am using only 2 videos as input. I then concat them to produce an output of 1280X720 output.

However, when I do that, I notice that it eats up all my memory of the server which has 16GB of memory and swp memory of 4GB.

Before I start encode process, swap memory is 2.95 GB and memory is about 1 - 1.5GB.

The encoding works for approximately 7 mins 37 seconds everytime I run it. Then the memory and swp memory is all filled and ffmpeg exits with no response.

My ffmpeg command is:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -stats -fflags +genpts+discardcorrupt -nostdin -re -i /home/bardan/content/BBB.mp4 -re -i /home/bardan/content/TOS.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v0];[1:v]scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,fps=25,format=yuv420p[v1];[0:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a0];[1:a]aformat=sample_rates=44100:channel_layouts=stereo[a1];[v0][a0][v1][a1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vconcat][aconcat];[vconcat]split=2[vloop0][vloop1];[aconcat]asplit=2[aloop0][aloop1];[vloop0][aloop0][vloop1][aloop1]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vlooped][alooped]" -map "[vlooped]" -map "[alooped]" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2500k -c:a aac -movflags +faststart -f flv -flvflags no_duration_filesize -shortest  -max_delay 0.5 -vsync 0 rtmp://{rtmp_url}:1935/livehd/livestreamloop_720p2500kbs
```

I have been struggling to find a solution to this for the past few days. Been searching the web for solutions and I even tried getting solution using chatgpt. The above command is the last suggestion made by chatgpt. I could not even find any answer to my problem on stackoverflow.

However, to no avail, I am bound to seek suggestions from my friends on stackoverflow to help me overcome the issue.

BTW, I have been using ffmpeg for simple encoding. But concat and filter together is something I haven't understood fully yet.

Comment: Why are you restricting your swap if you know the process needs it? The only conclusion you can come to right now is you need >20GB RAM.

Comment: @Tetsujin I am not restricting anything. I just don't understand why this command is eating up all my memory and swp memory. Hmmm.... Ok. Let me see if that can help. I will try that and see if raising RAM helps. Let me also hear out other options if anyone else has any solution.

Comment: You're thinking the wrong way round. 4GB swap is highly restrictive. I'm used to Mac where swap is flexible… but it starts by being able to allocate 8 exabytes - basically every space on every drive.

Comment: If your process never releases memory, though, you'll run out of room whatever you do… it will just take longer.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's the problem. If ffmpeg would have become slower and taken longer time that would have been ok. But ffmpeg stops abruptly as soon as the RAM and swp memory is full.

Basically, I want to concat all the videos in a folder and then produce a live stream in a loop. ffmpeg stops and returns nothing at around 7mins 37 seconds everytime.

Comment: Well… that will be because your machine runs out of memory - because you've got a restricted swap for some unknown reason. Wasn't it Einstein who said the first sign of madness is repeating the same experiment & hoping for a different result? At least if you give it a decent amount of swap you'll quickly discover if the function will eventually work, or if it will just continue to eat every resource until it eventualy fails.

Comment: Thanks. I will talk to my systems guys tomorrow to see the possibility of extending swap memory. Maybe that will help.